# Why isn't my spinner getting populated

Tags: java, android

So I have two classes, MainActivity and SpinnerActivity.

Whatever I do now, my spinner just doesn't get populated with the data from the topicsAdapter which uses the topics ArrayList.

Maybe it's just something easy i've stumbled upon, but I just can't figure it out.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    Intent spinner = new Intent(this, SpinnerActivity.class);
    startActivity(spinner);
}
```

SpinnerActivity.java

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);


    ArrayList<String> topics = new ArrayList<>();

    topics.add("Home");
    topics.add("Android");
    topics.add("Test 3");

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> topicsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, topics);
    topicsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown);
    spinner.setAdapter(topicsAdapter);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue** : you are creating a separate view (by inflating it) and has no connection with the layout of current `SpinnerActivity` and spinner is also being created in that unrelated view.

Solutions :

You can do `setContentView(view);` to use the spinner which is inside the inflated view

or

if you have spinner in your layout then use(**seems like it is otherwise it would have been crashed**)

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_spinner);
```

and remove

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out that way. I now completely understand what my mistake was and how easily I could've avoided it. 
I remember that I did the view.findViewById because otherwise Android Studio flagged it as 'cannot resolve symbol', but most likely this was due to another mistake.
Kinda frustrating if you cant figure it out but everyone else spots it in less than a minute ._.

Comment: i am glad that i could help, keep it up

Answer (score 0):

You should change `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` to layout file where this Spinner located. 
BTW you should remove these lines

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
```

Comment: it is already in `activity_main` otherwise there would have been a crash, look carefully

Comment: but first activity named MainActivity have the same XML file as second one, so it should be moved away to second's activity layout file

Comment: hence my answer and comment

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with this :-

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<String> topics = new ArrayList<>();

    topics.add("Home");
    topics.add("Android");
    topics.add("Test 3");

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> topicsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, topics);
    topicsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown);
    spinner.setAdapter(topicsAdapter);

}
```